# Forcing exactly the same column widths in table

Tags: tables

Based on [Writing descriptions of columns of table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54889/writing-descriptions-of-columns-of-table)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\label{fig:ieee754single}
\centering\sf\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.45pt}
\begin{tabular}{|*{32}{c|}}
\multicolumn{32}{|l}{\small  Bit}\\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\footnotesize  31}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  24}&
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\footnotesize  23}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  16}&
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\footnotesize  15}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  8}&
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\footnotesize  7}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  0}\\
\hline
S &
E & E & E & E & E & E & E & E &
M & M & M & M & M & M & M & M &
M & M & M & M & M & M & M & M &
M & M & M & M & M & M & M \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}&
\multicolumn{8}{c|}{Wykładnik} &
\multicolumn{23}{c|}{Mantysa} \\
\cline{2-32}
\multicolumn{5}{|c}{\raisebox{-0.3ex}{Znak}} & \multicolumn{27}{c}{}\\
\cline{1-5}
\end{tabular}
\rm\caption{IEEE754 single}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How can I force column widths to be the same. I like the width of E under 23.

Comment: possible duplicate of [columns width of array environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54959/columns-width-of-array-environment)

Comment: Try it with `p{<width>}` instead of `c` as column specifier.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{|*{32}{p{\widthof{M}}|}}` will work better than an `E` as the `M` is wider.  This requires [the `calc` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc).

Comment: Martin, using `p` works for width setting but I lose centering of letters inside cells... Peter, ...but '23' is wider than 'M'...

Comment: Then try `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{<width>}`.

Comment: @Martin, I'm not able to paste it correctly. `\begin{tabular}{|*{32}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{9.5pt}|}}` does not work.

Comment: @Ichibann: This need the common `array` package, see me answer now.

Comment: @Ichibann: The `23` is not boxed so does not affect the size of the box (at least that is how i saw it).

Comment: isn't this the same table asked about in question [writing-descriptions-of-columns-of-table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54889/writing-descriptions-of-columns-of-table)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, It's the same table. I think it is why OP wrote 'Based on'. As far as I understand, that question was about adding descriptions of columns. This question is about setting with of columns.

Comment: @Ichibann -- i still have the same problem with the vertical positioning of the cell contents in Martin Scharrer's answer, but i see that you have avoided that problem in your answer with good visual centering.  you might want to edit your answer to make that clear.  it's a problem too often overlooked in tables, and it grates on my sensibilities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the column width only with the paragraph `p` column type. In order to get centering you need to add `\centering` before, usually followed by `\arraybackslash` to restore the tabular meaning of `\\`.
You can do so using the `>{..}` column specifier provided by the `array` package. It also allows you to define you own custom column types.
I would suggest you do:

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2ex}}
```

and then use `C` instead of `c`.
There is also a lower-level TeX way to do it, which I added below. It lowers the text a little, which looks better IMHO.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}

% Normal LaTeX way: \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2ex}}
% Using lower-level TeX commands:
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\lower.2ex\hbox to 2ex\bgroup\hss}c<{\hss\egroup}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering\sf\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.45pt}
\begin{tabular}{|*{32}{C|}}
\multicolumn{32}{|l}{\small  Bit}\\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\footnotesize  31}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  24}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\footnotesize  23}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  16}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\footnotesize  15}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  8}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\footnotesize  7}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  0}\\
\hline
S &
E & E & E & E & E & E & E & E &
M & M & M & M & M & M & M & M &
M & M & M & M & M & M & M & M &
M & M & M & M & M & M & M \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}&
\multicolumn{8}{c|}{Wykładnik} &
\multicolumn{23}{c|}{Mantysa} \\
\cline{2-32}
\multicolumn{5}{|c}{\raisebox{-0.3ex}{Znak}} & \multicolumn{27}{c}{}\\
\cline{1-5}
\end{tabular}
\rmfamily
\caption{IEEE754 single}
\label{fig:ieee754single}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Please also note my other changes (`\label` after `\caption`, `\rmfamily` instead of `\rm`, ..).

[image: Result]

Comment: Why `\label` after `\caption` and what is a difference between `\rm` and `\rmfamily`?

Comment: `\label` always labels the last command which increases an official LaTeX counter (`\section`, `\caption`, etc.) and will label the wrong thing if not after or inside `\caption`. `\rm` is an old LaTeX2.0 macro and `\rmfamily` the correct LaTeX2e macro which supports the modern font selection scheme. See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516) for more details.

Comment: So should I use `\sfseries` in `\centering\sf\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.45pt}`?

Comment: This looks very nice. Too bad 64-bit `double` will not fit on the page. Eccept... I do it other way.

Comment: @papciuch: Yes, `\sfseries` instead of `\sf`. I didn't see that.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, I think it is `\sffamily`, not `\sfseries`.

Comment: @Ichibann: Yes, it's indeed `\sffamily`.

Comment: BTW, why would they name them inconsistently? One time it's `family`, other time `series`...

Answer (score 3):

Here you have 32- and 64-bit representation of `float` and `double` variable. If you like `±` instead of `Znak` it will be good one. I think so ;).
Do you like it?

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}

% Normal LaTeX way: \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2ex}}
% Using lower-level TeX commands:
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\lower.2ex\hbox to 2ex\bgroup\hss}c<{\hss\egroup}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering\sffamily\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.45pt}
\begin{tabular}{|*{32}{C|}}
\multicolumn{32}{l}{\raisebox{-0.3ex}{\small Bit}}\\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\footnotesize  31}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  24}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\footnotesize  23}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  16}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\footnotesize  15}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  8}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\footnotesize  7}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  0}\\
\hline
S &
E & E & E & E & E & E & E & E &
M & M & M & M & M & M & M & M &
M & M & M & M & M & M & M & M &
M & M & M & M & M & M & M \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\raisebox{-0.2ex}{$\pm$}}&
\multicolumn{8}{c|}{\raisebox{-0.2ex}{\small Wykładnik}} &
\multicolumn{23}{c|}{\raisebox{-0.2ex}{\small Mantysa}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\rmfamily
\caption{IEEE754 single}
\label{fig:ieee754single}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering\sffamily\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.45pt}
\begin{tabular}{|*{32}{C|}}
\multicolumn{32}{l}{\raisebox{-0.3ex}{\small Bit}}\\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\footnotesize  63}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  56}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\footnotesize  55}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  48}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\footnotesize  47}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  40}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\footnotesize  39}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  32}\\
\hline
S &
E & E & E & E & E & E & E & E &
E & E & E &
M & M & M & M & M & M & M & M &
M & M & M & M & M & M & M & M &
M & M & M & M\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\raisebox{-0.2ex}{$\pm$}}&
\multicolumn{11}{c|}{\raisebox{-0.2ex}{\small Wykładnik}} &
\multicolumn{20}{c|}{\raisebox{-0.2ex}{\small Mantysa}} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{32}{c}{}\\[-1.2ex]
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\footnotesize  31}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  24}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\footnotesize  23}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  16}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\footnotesize  15}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  8}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\footnotesize  7}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize  0}\\
\hline
M & M & M & M & M & M & M & M &
M & M & M & M & M & M & M & M &
M & M & M & M & M & M & M & M &
M & M & M & M & M & M & M & M\\
\hline
\multicolumn{32}{|c|}{\raisebox{-0.2ex}{\small Mantysa}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\rmfamily
\caption{IEEE754 double}
\label{fig:ieee754double}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I like it :)